# Extending HTML elements in Web components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

From the [custom elements](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/custom-elements/) page, I see that to extend an element you do:

```
var XFooButtonPrototype = Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype);
XFooButtonPrototype.createdCallback = function() {
  this.textContent = "I'm an x-foo button!";
};

var XFooButton = document.registerElement('x-foo-button', {
  prototype: XFooButtonPrototype,
  extends: 'button'
});
```

Then later in the guide it says that you can make an element by writing either:

```
<x-foo></x-foo>
```

Or:

```
<button is="x-foo-button"></button>
```

Questions:

- Why is it important to specify `extends: 'button'` when the element is obviously_ inheriting from `HTMLButtonElement` (since it has `HTMLButtonElement.prototype` in its proto chain)
- How is the link between `button` and `x-foo-button` established? Does `x-foo-button` become a possible option of button in terms of `is="x-foo-button"` thanks to that `extends: 'button'` ? What happens "internally", so to speak?
- Why would you pick `<button is="x-foo-button"></button>` over `<x-foo></x-foo>`...?

**[ADDENDUM]**

Polymer saves us from this duplication:

```
MyInput = Polymer({
  is: 'my-input',
  extends: 'input',
  created: function() {
    this.style.border = '1px solid red';
  }
});
```

If `extends` is there, Polymer will put the right prototype in the chain with `Object.getPrototypeOf(document.createElement(tag));`.
So, corollary question:

- Why the duplication in the first place? If there is an `extends`, shouldn't the browser automatically do this?

Comment: I don't think both of the syntaxes you mentioned are interchangeable. Under _using a custom element_ section wiki states that : 

_If you've used extends to create a custom element that derives from an
existing DOM element (e.g. something other than HTMLElement), use the is syntax_

Comment: Ta, posted an answer. Thanks a million for the comment!

Answer (score 4):

You totally misunderstood how extending web components work.

## Create simple elements

First of all, this is how you register a new element:

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

To create an element you can do one of these:

```
<x-foo></x-foo>

var xFoo = new XFoo();
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);

var xFoo = document.createElement( 'x-foo')
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);
```

## Create extended elements

This is how you extend an existing element:

```
var XFooButton = document.registerElement('x-foo-button', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLButtonElement.prototype),
  extends: 'button'
});
```

To create one you can do one of these:

```
<button is="x-foo-button"></button>

var xFooButton = new XFooButton();
document.body.appendChild(xFoo);

var xFooButton = document.createElement('button', 'x-foo-button');
document.body.appendChild(xFooButton);
```

Note that in case of extended custom elements, when registering them you have to specify both the prototype (set to `HTMLButtonElement.prototype` rather than `HTMLElement.prototype`), *and* the extended tag's name (`extends: 'button'`).

Also, when you create an extended element using markup or `createElement()`, you need to also specify the basic element (`button`) and the extended one (`x-foo-button`),

(Note: I am aware I am answering myself)

Comment: Maybe the "is" syntax will be deprecated

Comment: I heard they are trying to come up with something better than the "is" syntax, but couldn't, so far.

Comment: @Merc, the Web Platform WG on their mailing-list: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2015AprJun/0608.html

Answer (score 0):

I think its Importent to Say here:

**WARNING DEPRECATED Browser API METHOD**
Here in this Question a .registerElement is Used it got Replaced by .defineElement and the Api has changed

**current way to define a element**

```js
class AppDrawer extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.innerHTML = '<h1>UH</h1>'    
  }
}

window.customElements.define('app-drawer', AppDrawer);

// Or use an anonymous class if you don't want a named constructor in current scope.

window.customElements.define('app-drawer-noname', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.innerHTML = '<h1>UH AH</h1>'    
  }
});
```

```html
Example - defining a mobile drawer panel, < app - drawer >:
Example usage:
<app-drawer></app-drawer>
<app-drawer-noname></app-drawer-noname>
```

```